# Editing text from Master Page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

In InDesgin, if I create an object (a tinted rectangle, for example) with a blank text frame inside it on a master page, will I be able to enter text on my document pages?

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I'd rather not have to copy/paste these rectangles onto every page of this document since they are positioned identically on each page.

Answer (score 5):

You can **<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click** on an object on a page to individually override the Master page object.

Using the above shortcut, you can click the text frame on the page to allow it to be edited on the page. Note, doing so no longer links that text frame to the Master Page. Future changes to the Master Page will *not* result in updates to objects which have been individually overridden on pages.

Master page items are generally for things which will *not* be edited on every page. This is sort of why InDesign gives you the *option* of `Master Page Text Frame` when you create new Master Pages.

Comment: Hey Scott, I'm using InDesign CC 2018 and can't find Master Page Text Frame when I create a new Master Page, where exactly can I chose this option?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this...

Should you have a master page which does not require editable text AS WELL AS a set of master pages which do, you can create a new master page BASED ON the original (drop down option in New Master menu) and then apply it to the pages which require editable text.

Just use the <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+**click** method to edit those text boxes.